# Formatting Stata post-estimation results for LaTeX

Tags: latex, stata

I want to write a TeX file in Stata which contains a p-value rounded to the nearest .001. Since sutex, outtab, etc doesn't have built-in capabilities for post-estimation results, I've tried a bunch of things like

```
file write myfile %4z "`r(p)'"
```

or

```
gen temp = round( `r(p)',.001)
format temp %4.3f
sum temp, f
file write myfile " & `r(mean)'"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example which writes the p-value from a t-test into a text file. The p-value is rounded to the third decimal.

```
sysuse auto, clear
ttest price, by(fore)
file open myfile using "foo.txt", write replace
file write myfile "price & " %5.3f (r(p)) " \\"
file close myfile 
type "foo.txt"
```

I have specified a `5.3f` format. The first number means that the output will have a width of 5. This width includes the decimal point. The second number means that there will be three digits following the decimal point. Have a look at `help format` if you want to know more about this notation and about other options you have.

The parentheses surrounding `r(p)` mean that this expression will be avluated and the result will be written into the file. This is explained in `help file`.